# Handling data copied from remote databases

Tags: database

We have a contracts database that pulls data from our job management system overnight using a simple stored procedure.  The stored proc simply deletes the data from the local table and refills with the new data copied across.  Obviously this means we cannot set up any relationships to this data in the local table / database.  Does anyone have any good strategy ideas to improve on this so that we can set up the correct relationships to this table.  How can I handle a deleted record in the remote table if a relationship to this record has been established in the local table as just deleting it would break the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are talking about a syncing problem. As in, how can you make the associations when the data is blown away and recreated every night?

What I would do is create nullable foreign keys on the local data that needs to reference it. The stored procedure should null all the foreign keys on the various local tables when the new data is coming in. Then, when the data is restored from the remote database, have the stored procedure then go through and shore up the foreign keys again to re-create the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

How about truncating the table instead of deleting it?

If you are using SQL Server: [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)